# known hacker and IT specialist obsessed with collecting data from my phone

Tags: mobile, phone

It seems that a person I used to work with is an IT specialist and obsessed with collecting data got a hold of my phone. From the looks of it, they are using metasploit to listen in and record texts and locations.

I got the elixir app and found commands I send SMS they get location and certain apps all log apps. Security apps do not open anymore. I have log files that I do not know how to read.

I need to stop this invasion of privacy. I know they have done this to others because we used to work together and they told me about it.

Comment: I did my best to try and make sense of your question, but it is very difficult to understand. If your device is infected, factory reset it.

Comment: "From the look of it they are using metasploit" - can you describe what that means. What forensics have you done to identify metasploit as the tool used.

Comment: Actually, scratch that - just factory reset it as Schroeder said.

Answer (score 4):

If you suspect that your smartphone has been hacked, you should mimic a hacked computer process:

- save all data to an external media
- do a factory reset to your phone
- change all your network passwords
- re-install only trusted apps, and the least possible of them
- ensure that the saved data is safe through an up to date anti-malware - anti-virus
- restore the data.

There is still a risk that the firmware has been compromised, but IMHO this risk is low, so the freshly re-installed phone should be safe.

But do not forget to put a *correct* password on the SIM card and on the phone itself with an *acceptable* timeout.